# Redux SAGA sideEffect handler doesn't work when downloading React bundle for first time

Tags: reactjs, redux, bundle, redux-saga

I'm working on a large scale project in which we're using Redux SAGA.
The Redux SAGA handles about 180 side effects and the whole codebase is pretty big.
I'm using lazy loading to handle downloading fewer bundle bundle size at the first time, but there's a problem.

I've recently found out that when opening the website (with new bundle) for the first time, the `spawn` action works, but the `takeLatest` or any other sideEffect Handler that takes a redux Action doesn't work.

It fixes when I refresh the page and open the website again, when it takes the `js` bundles from the catch for the second time. If I close and reopen the `incognito`, I can see this issue again. (no side effect handler works for the first time)

I've checked the whole SAGA several times and it's totally okay.

Do you have any idea about how to fix such issue?

Comment: This sounds like a race condition. Can you provide more info about your app? What is being lazy loaded - just react components or sagas/reducers/etc as well? If you lazy load sagas/reducers how do you inject them to the app, do you use any 3rd party solution? Is the failing `takeLatest` in a lazy loaded chunk or in an entry chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was running SAGA middleware in `App.tsx`.
When I took the `sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);` code into the Router component, it fixed, because the router component is the heaviest component (with a lot of route components, some of them are not splitted) and of course using `useLayoutEffect` was another trick.
So puting this component:

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  }, []);

  .....
}
```

in the first big component in the application hierarchy (this one is the most important thing you should do) will fix the issue of not running SAGA properly on the first download of the app bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Worth's a shot trying changing your `useEffect` that dispatch your sagas to `useLayoutEffect`, so it would only call saga when the DOM finishs loading aka when finishing bundle download.